# True, False, Null in SQL

Tags: sql

I already know that True and True returns True, True and False returns False
but how about True and null?
I don't know the answer. Please help me!!

Comment: What's the name of your RDMS (SQL Server, Oracle, PosgreSQL, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)):

Note: `Unknown` is `NULL`.

```
p        q        p AND q
--------------------------
True     True     True
True     False    False
True     Un­known  Un­known
False    True     False
False    False    False
False    Un­known  False
Un­known  True     Un­known
Un­known  False    False
Un­known  Un­known  Un­known
```

In short, `TRUE AND NULL` yields `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

It returns NULL. Try this:

`SELECT 1 & 1`
This will return 1 (True and True returns True)

`SELECT 1 & 0`
This will return 0 (True and False returns False)

`SELECT 1 & NULL`
This will return NULL (True and NULL returns NULL)

The common way of comparing nulls is by replacing the null value to a default like 0 or empty string:
`IF ISNULL(@value,0) = 0`

Comment: Note that 1 for TRUE, `&` and `ISNULL` are all product specific. ANSI/ISO SQL has `TRUE` for TRUE, `AND` for AND, and `COALESCE()` to get the first non-null value.